# Using strcmp() function with pointer array in C program

Tags: c, strcmp

I'm trying to detect duplicate strings in a pointer array. I want to detect if there is any duplication with strcmp() function and want to remove duplications except the first one however the command line is giving error when I add `strcmp()` function : `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Here is my code;
and size is equal to size of the products array.

```
FILE* temp_file_to_read = fopen("temp.txt", "r");
char temp_line[256];  
char *products[256];
int j = 0;
        while(fgets(temp_line, sizeof(temp_line), temp_file_to_read)){
                //printf("%s", temp_line);
                products[j] = strdup(temp_line);
                printf("%s", products[j]);
                j++;
        }


         for(int i = 0; i< size; i++){
                    for(int j = i+1; j <  size; j++){
                            if(strcmp(products[i], products[j])==0){
                                    printf("%s is exist\n", products[j]);
                            }
                    }
            }
```

Comment: This is a situation where you should narrow the problem down using your debugger.

Comment: "giving segmentation fault error" - where???

Comment: @goodvibration sorry I edited it. If I use strcmp() to check duplications it occurs.

Comment: Yes, that one was already stated. However, you should by the least do some debugging and tell us which line of code yields the segmentation fault! And by the way, you also need to ensure that the `while` loop doesn't continue when `j` reaches 256.

Comment: Those `for` loops imply that `products` array contains 256 valid pointers, which is not necessary true. Another error here is that `j` inside of loop shadows `j` from outer scope.

Comment: @goodvibration while loop ends at the end of last line, it's ok. I found the size of array and edited the code. My main problem is to compare duplications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that your file doesn't have 256 products that are exactly 256 characters in length each, so your `products` array isn't full. So when you do `strcmp(products[i], products[j])`, you will at some point be trying to use garbage pointers as if they point to a genuine string, and that's where you're getting a segfault.

There are several things wrong with your code, including

- you probably want to be breaking up your file at new lines, not just every 256 characters (though I could be wrong)
- you should check to make sure you don't try to create more than 256 products, otherwise you'll overflow your array
- when doing the string comparisons, only go as far as the number of products you have, rather than blindly to the end of the array

Comment: Thanks for your help, @goodvibration also stated that and I re-edited the code. It solved the st fault. Clear explanation!